# How do i define Jquery button styles?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have been working on a jquery mobile page and it has several buttons on it that have unique styles for example:

As part of a sort of client side "jquery driven wizard" have ...

```
<button data-function="back" class="back">Back</button>
<button data-function="next" class="next">Next</button>
<button data-function="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
```

... depending on where you are in the wizard these buttons are shown / hidden.

Not a problem ... until I get to the styles.
JQuery takes it upon itself to "wrap my button and hide it" so i end up with something that looks like ...

```
<div class="ui-btn ...">    
   <span class="ui-btn-inner ...">Back</span>
   <button class="back">Back</button> 
</div>
```

As stated above, it hides my button, and my custom style for the back button is then effectively lost.
I don't want to style all buttons just my custom ones.

I thought about using some JQuery to move my custom style to the parent "div" element as part of a doc ready script but this just seems stupid to have to do for each button and the logic could get quite complex or long winded if I have to do this every time i want a different button type.

Is there a standard way of saying "JQuery, I want this class applied to the button element(s) you generate ... " or is this a bug?

I have noticed that others avoid using this aproach altogether for example ...
http://m.nationalrail.co.uk/pj/home

Visiting the official JQuery mobile page on buttons appears to exhibit the same behaviour:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos//1.2.0/docs/buttons/buttons-types.html

(remember to change your browser agent to a mobile device before visiting)

Any ideas?
Ideally I want to avoid "hacking" the styles to the right element with some JQuery of my own to avoid slowing the page down and introducing more code I then have to maintain just because I want a blue and an orange button next to each other.

Trouble is this is for our corporate main landing page so the style is considered quite important.

Edit for @Gajotres:

Adding another theme may solve the problem but my remit for this page is for it to perform as quickly as possible and loading up the page with multiple themes would mean more loading time.

I have considered something like this as being a possible solution but I think that JQuery should be already doing this so my thought was that maybe i'm doing something wrong ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var allButtons = $(button);
   allButtons.each(function() { 
      var css = $(this).className;
      $(this).prev().addClass(css);
   });
</script>
```

This would result in me applying any classes on the button to the span tag that jquery has generated and is now showing in it's place.
I would then need to append some further functionality to ensure that I selectively copy of over certain classes (just dumb imo).

Taking the JQuery aproach here i could add something like ...

```
data-customStyle="myClass"
```

... to each button i want to style then use something like ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var customButtons = $("data-customStyle");
   customButtons.each(function() { 
      $(this).prev().addClass($(this).data("customStyle"));
   });
</script>
```

... to append the style to the "jquery tag that represents the button".

My thought on this ...
WTF?!?!

JQuery is all about making life easier not harder surely?
I shouldn't have to "post hack add in" stuff to do what I basically already did on the server and JQuery broke.

Is this a bug in JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in the end fell in to the domain of the first c in css.

If you put your style sheets on the page in the right order you can take advantage of the cascade to override things correctly.

JQuery is aggressive as all hell with its "default styles" and some persistence usually pays off although it may mean overriding a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Find the css file that is associated with the jQuery and try to edit that with reference to the divs that you need styling and those that you dont need styling. Else for those buttons that you dont want styling, just change the class or id to a different name that wont exist in the css file.

Sometimes even if you change class (in css class name is after a dot example ".class") or id (in css id name is after a hash "#id"), if not all, sometimes small changes like background color may remain the same. For this check the css file that corresponds to the main attribute like  or  or   (in css attribute name is is placed between square brackets example "[title]"). For reference you can check http://www.w3schools.com/css/

Comment: wouldn't it be better to create another css file with custom classes created by him that override the default css?

Comment: Yes you could do that and thats the same as editing the current one and saving it in a different name. And also if the css is included in the php or the .js you have to change the inclusion from the old css to the new one.

Comment: Its worth noting that I already have a second stylesheet with my custom button style in it, i'm trying to figure out how to apply it to my "jquery modified dom" the parent element and the span generated next to my buttons do not contain my custom css style (jquery isn't copying it to the element it generates)

Comment: If you look at the markup i provided, on the server i render a simple button tag, on the client jquery wraps that and places a span tag next to it hiding my button tag and thus my custom style with it.